# Why am I getting "The directory contains entries whose names differ only by case"

Tags: vbscript

I am attempting to revamp a code with some updated features, but now when I run it, no matter which end option I select it won't do anything beyond give me an error when attempting to rename files or copy them. What does it mean when it say object required and then the err text is  "The directory contains entries whose names differ only by case".  I've never seen it before.
Here is my script:

```
set ws = createobject("wscript.shell")
Set fs = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
set sa = createobject("shell.application")

            Set ie=CreateObject("internetexplorer.application") 
            ie.AddressBar=False
            ie.navigate "about:blank"
            ie.Height=1900
            ie.Width=3300
            ie.Top=50
            ie.Left=50
            Do While ie.Busy
            WScript.Sleep 1000
            Loop
sa.minimizeall          
Function find_file

qc = vbNo
Do While qc =vbNo

Set Browsed = sa.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please select the folder.",4001, "")
If Not (Browsed Is Nothing) Then
Set BF=fs.GetFolder(browsed.self.path)
qc = MsgBox("That's Great. We're looking for files in "&vbCrLf&bf.Path&"!"&vbCrLf&"Is this correct",vbYesNo,"Is this the right folder?")
If bf.Files.Count=0 Then
qc = vbNo
d = MsgBox("There are no files in the dirctory chosen."&vbCrLf&"Please try again!",vbYesNo +vbExclamation,"Uh-Oh")
If d = vbNo Then ender
End if
Else
Call Ender
End If

Loop

ie.Visible=true
IE.Document.write "<body>The Files in " & bf.Path & " are:<br><br>"

For Each files In bf.Files
a = a & files.Name & "<br>"

Next
ie.Document.write "<div style='width:90%;height:70%;overflow:scroll;' id='mydiv'>"&a&"</div>"


rep1=InputBox("Great! What are we changing?","Text that should be replaced or removed from the file(s)","")
rep2=InputBox("Are we just erasing that or replacing it with something?","Replace or Erase text (Default is Erase)","")
ie.quit
c = MsgBox("Last question, just rename (Cannot undo!)",vbYesNo,"Rename or Duplicate Files with the New Names?")
MoveCopy c
ws.Popup "We're all done!"&vbCrLf&"Later!",4,"Job Well Done!"

Set ie = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
sa.UndoMinimizeALL
Set sa = Nothing

WScript.Quit
End Function


find_file
Sub ender

ws.Popup "I thought we were working. My bad!"&vbCrLf&"Later!",4,"My Mistake"
ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
sa.UndoMinimizeALL
Set sa = Nothing

WScript.Quit
End Sub

function MoveCopy(c)

If c = vbNo Then
ws.Popup "Just a few moments.  We will create the renamed files in:" & vbCrLf & fs.GetAbsolutePathName(copied.Path) & vbCrLf &"Hold tight!",4,"Please wait..."
Set copied=fs.CreateFolder(".\Renamed")
Set copied=fs.getfolder(".\Renamed")
Else
ws.Popup "Just a few moments.  We will rename files in:" & vbCrLf & files.path & vbCrLf &"Hold tight!",4,"Please wait..."
End if

For Each files In bf.Files
aa = fs.GetBaseName(files)
bb = Replace(aa,rep1,rep2)
file2 = Replace(files.name,aa,bb)
Set dd = fs.getfile(files.Path)

If c = vbno Then


dd.Copy ".\Renamed\" & files2
else
fs.movefile dd.path, ".\"&files2


End If
Next
End function
```

[image: Error Box]

Comment: I didn't want to step through this code, but I get the sense that the intent is to bulk rename files? Or perhaps copy and rename? If so, I would suggest using quality tools such as [Bulk Rename Utility](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk), [FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp), [WinMerge](https://winmerge.org/?lang=en), etc.

Comment: You could start by properly identing your code so it's actually readable.

Comment: Your code is completely illegible: *PLEASE* learn to indent and format!  I can't even tell if the code is legal (i.e. if it will compile without errors).  NEVERTHELESS: the problem is obvious.  Code in your MoveCopy will FAIL if source and destination filenames are the same.

Comment: @LesFerch Strangely enough, I have each of those programs, but I was hoping to do this programmatically for simplicity. In most cases, I have a set of images or audio files that I need to make a quick adjustment for a specific purpose (ie. renaming numerically for randomization on a website.)

Comment: The example you give sounds like just the thing BRU does well. And you can program it to a point by using regular expressions. If you really want to roll your own, you certainly can achieve your goals using VBScript, but you might want to consider switching to PowerShell. The way it's structured around objects and piping makes it a great choice for these sorts of problems and you'll find a much larger user base for getting help. I'm sure a great case could also be made for using Python. P.S. Not a fan of the cutesy prompts. I would focus on making a solid command line tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can sometimes get the misleading system message `This directory contains entries whose names differ only in case` when an object has not been defined.

It's important to focus on the actual error, which, in this case, is `object required 'Files'`.

Objects should be named uniquely to avoid conflicts with reserved words and other objects, the object name must be defined with a global `Dim` if it's to be used outside of a single sub or function, and `Option Explicit` is recommended to avoid typos that lead to object errors.

The `Files` object in this case breaks most, if not all, of those rules.

Comment: Sound advice as always.  I had considered that object naming was the issue, but when clearly naming I ran into the same issue.  I think I might have come down with something.
This problem pushed me to work harder and then my system crashed.  Now I am using my available time to learn poweshell and then on to Python.   I was always better at herpetology than coding, anyway!